# How to initilize an array of integers in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I want to initialize an array of integers in Dafny but I got the error msg "Error: call might violate context's modifies clause". The code I have is

```
class shap {
  var intarray:array<int>; 
  constructor (i:int) 
    requires i>0
  {
      this.intarray := new int[i];
  }
  method init(i: int)
    modifies intarray
  {
   var index:int:=0;
   while (index<intarray.Length){
      intarray[index]:=i;
      index:=index+1;
    }
  }
}

method Main(){
  var sh:= new shap(5);
  sh.init(4);
}
```

When I compile the code I get "Error: call might violate context's modifies clause" when calling init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Ensure from your constructor that the array is fresh.

To debug a message "Error: call might violate context's modifies clause" when calling init method.", you can explicit what Dafny should believes is the set of things it is allowed to modify, which are the objects in the enclosing modified clause, plus all the fresh objects

```
method Main()
  modifies {}
{
  ghost var allowedToModify: set<object> := {}; // Whatever is in your modifies clause
  var sh:= new shap(5);
  ghost var modifiesFromShInit4 := {sh.intarray}; // Whatever is in the modifies clause of the next call.
  assert fresh(modifiesFromShInit4 -allowedToModify); // Necessary so that the call below can modify objects
  sh.init(4);
}
```

Now you can see that the assertion fails but the call succeeds, it means you have probably isolated the problem.
Because `allowedToModify` is empty, what you need is `fresh({sh.intarray})`. Because the constructor does not say anything about that, Dafny cannot infer it easily, especially because methods are opaque.
So what you need to do is add an `ensures` clause in your constructor that tell that the array is fresh:

```
  constructor (i:int) 
    requires i>0
    ensures fresh(intarray)
  {
      this.intarray := new int[i];
  }
```

From that, Dafny is happy, and you can remove intermediate ghost code that was just used to debug.

Comment: Yes that does it. thanks for the info. This brings another question **you can explicit what Dafny should believes is the set of things it is allowed to modify ...** how would someone can find such a set?

Comment: At the beginning of the method, it's the set described in the modifies clause.
After every method call that ensures fresh(B) for some B, it's the set of things allowed to be modified before the call + B